# SonarQube view only newly introduced issues in specific branch

Tags: git, sonarqube

I'd like to view the issues introduced in a specific git branch, in comparison to a master branch. Is this possible in SonarQube?

I work with a branching system where every jira issue has it's own branch and I want to integrate SonarQube in my reviewing proces. The review is done by another programmer, so a local preview analysis is not an option.

Issue overview based on a specific time period is not applicable to my situation.

I've had a look at the analysis mode of Sonarqube. The incremental mode seems to be what I need (only new changes), but I'd need all of the changes introduced in the branch, not only the latest commit.
Preview is just another full analysis, so it wouldn't help me much further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [GitHub plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin), for analysis of pull requests. Assuming you're using Git on GitHub, I believe the only modification that would be required to the workflow you've described is the addition of a pull request step.

Comment: Hi G. Ann, Thanks for your answer. I'm not using Github for my project hosting. I am using atlassian stash/bitbucket, but the performance of the Sonar4Stash plugin is so bad it's not usable.